# C# - How to get certain generic types from an assembly using linq

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to find types in an assembly that are of ISomeInterface< AnyType >  using linq.

How do I do this?

Here's what I have:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a=>a.GetTypes().Where(t=> /* t is ISomeInterface<ofAnyType> */))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (I'm not at a pc)

```
from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
from type in asm.GetTypes()
where (type.IsClass || type.IsStruct)
  && type.GetInterfaces().Any(
  intf => intf.IsGenericType
    && intf.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ISomeInterface<>))
select type;
```